# parameter tooltip not colored like oteher tooltips in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, tooltip, intellisense

Here is how tooltip looks like when you hover over function or any other identifier:

[image]

Here is how tooltip looks like when you query parameter info, for example when start filling function
parameter list:

[image]

I wan't in both cases colored tooltip, what setting do I need to adjust?

**UPDATE:**
Following suggestion to reset settings to factory defaults, I signed into fresh Admin account in windows, and opened up Visual Studio with fresh factory settings but there is no change, test screenshot:

[image]

Comment: Hi, any update for this issue, if it still blocks you please feel free to let me know:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's expected behavior that both cases are colored like this(for at least VS2017 and VS2019):

[image]

I'm not sure whether your issue comes from the unknown color setting or vs extensions, you can try Reset the VS IDE settings by `Tools=>Import and Export Settings=>Reset all settings=>No, just reset settings, overwrite=>General=>Finish` to get your text editor back to normal behavior.

And if it can't work, please disable the third-party extensions and restart VS to make it work.

**Updated:**

All above for C# Intellisense not C++. For C++ Intellisense, this option is not supported by IDE.

And if someone is interested in [this option](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/746938/parameter-tooltip-color-for-c.html), consider voting for it in DC.

Comment: Hi Lance, thank you for reply and sorry for delay, I was AFK up until now. I followed your suggestion, see edit in my question for updated image, still no change, I don't even remember I had colored parameter list for years, this should be enabled somewhere. edit: btw I see u work with C#, while my screenshots are from C++ editor, could that make a difference?

Comment: @metablaster I'm afraid that do make a difference. See [C++ Intellisense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-cpp-intellisense?view=vs-2019) and [C# Intellsense](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-csharp-intellisense?view=vs-2019), they have different Intellisense settings, and one is managed code while C++ isn't. I tried it in VS2019 right now and find this option only supports C#, VB.net but not C++.

Comment: @metablaster You may go [Developer community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html) to suggest a new feature about VS and if it gets enough votes, the team would consider adding this option for C++ also. Hope it helps :)

Comment: OK, I see, thank you for helping out! I posted proposal here: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/idea/746938/parameter-tooltip-color-for-c.html